# Kubernetes : If node lost, communication is intermittent with running Pods

Tags: kubernetes

Anyone has aware of this issue, I have a cluster of 3 nodes and Am running pods in statefulset. totally 3 pods are running in the order, assume  pod-0 running on node-1, pod-2 running on node-2, and pod-3 running on node-3.  now, the traffic is going properly and getting the response immediately, when we stop one node(eg: node-2) , then the response is intermittent and the traffic is routing to stopped pod as well, is there any solution/workaround for this issue.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should probably use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question. Also see [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center.

Answer (score 1):

> when we stop one node(eg: node-2), then the response is intermittent and the traffic is **routing to stopped pod as well**, is there any solution/workaround for this issue.

This seem to be a [reported issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/55713). However, Kubernetes is a distribued cloud native system and you should design for resilience with use of request retries.

- [Improve availability and resilience of your Microservices using these seven cloud design patterns](https://medium.com/asos-techblog/improve-availability-and-resilience-of-your-micro-services-using-this-7-cloud-design-patterns-16006eaf32b1)
- [How to Make Services Resilient in a Microservices Environment](https://dzone.com/articles/libraries-for-microservices-development)

Comment: Thanks Jonas, I will check the given links.